# is express.router compatible with endpoints over GCP?¡

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I developed in nodeJs some services that I want to move to GCP, the thing is that I implemented it using express.router, is there a way to move/configure GCP endpoints tu route my calls using express.router or I need to get rid of that router and make the routing in a more direct way?

Answer (score 1):

Is possible, you need to add express dependency to your package json and export the xrouter function.

I used this [example](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) to test express routing

```
package.json


{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}



index.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var router = express.Router()

// a middleware function with no mount path. This code is executed for every request to the router
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
console.log('Time:', Date.now())
next()
})

// a middleware sub-stack shows request info for any type of HTTP request to the /user/:id path
router.use('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl)
next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
console.log('Request Type:', req.method)
next()
})

// a middleware sub-stack that handles GET requests to the /user/:id path
router.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
// if the user ID is 0, skip to the next router
if (req.params.id === '0') next('route')
// otherwise pass control to the next middleware function in this stack
else next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
// render a regular page
res.send('regular')
})

// handler for the /user/:id path, which renders a special page
router.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
console.log(req.params.id)
res.send('special')
})

// mount the router on the app
app.use('/', router)

exports.xrouter = app;
```

the function that you need to invoke is xrouter